# People who have accepted (an invitation)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am sending invitations to people who are eligible to become members. I am wondering what other word I can use that means something similar to 'member'.

Specifically, I have invited certain people ('invitees'), and some of them have accepted my invitation.

I'm looking for a word like 'accepteds' (which I know is not the right word to use), because they *accepted* my invitation and so their status has changed from *invitee* to *XXXX* (a noun based on or associated with a verb that means 'to accept').

I know this sounds like a silly question, but in my own language you can name such people by reference to their action.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acceptee) **acceptee** is a real word, though I have to say I have never heard it actually used.

> acceptee (plural acceptees)
>   A person who accepts, or is accepted for, a position

Answer (score 0):

One convention is to keep a list of those invited and note next to their names  accepted, regretted, or no reply .  if you have many guests you can do this on a spread sheet and set it up so that it will calculate the totals for you.